# Python import module approaches

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces

I have created a package named mod and placed a python file inside it (a.k.a: module). The name of the python file is printme.py.

I import the module in the below couple of ways.

```
import mod.printme 

 ['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'mod']
```

After this is executed, the name space is appended with the value mod.
I expected this to have the value printme (which is the actual module name)

```
from mod import printme

['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'printme']
```

After this is executed, correctly the name space is appended with the value printme as expected.

Technically, both are expected to import the module printme in the local namespace, I am little puzzled why the first approach is NOT placing the printme module name in the local namespace.

Could someone please help me to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: in the first version you have to all a function in your module as `mod.printme.function()` - therefore `mod` needs to be accessible to python. in the second versioun you would call `printme.function()` - here only the name `printme` must be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `mod` to be a book and `printme.py` as a chapter.

When you are commanding that `import mod.printme` you are saying to python "Hey! Please bring mod book and it's printme chapter as a whole book and remove other chapters". Now whenever you need to reference content from this book you need to say `mod.printme.foo()` as the name of your new book is `mod` and it has only one chapter `printme`.

When you are commanding that `from mod import printme` you are saying: "Hey! Please bring print me chapter in mod book as a book in itself". Now whenever you need to reference content from this book you need to say `printme.foo()` as the chapter has become book so only name of book, in your case `printme`, is needed.

And if you want Python to bring all headings of chapter `printme` in your current book (the book you are writing, as in Python each file is a module) you may use `from mod.printme import *`. It will bring all headings only. So you need not to reference the `book/chapter`, just `foo()` will work.

They works this way because they are made to work this way.

Comment: However, do not use `from mod.printme import *` as it will make namespace a mess. Instead use `from mod.printme import foo`

Comment: It is nice analogy to understand the concept in a much better way. Thanks for taking your time to look into the question.